# Conditionally Change Cell Color

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, cell

I would like to change the cell color of the specified cell in the `DataGridView` if the `InvoiceNo` is found in the database.

Below is my query:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    invoiceno = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    accpacInv = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Customer = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    Invdate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Duedate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    cur = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    LocAm = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DbClass.StrdBase);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select InvoiceNo from tblarmon     where invoiceno = '" + invoiceno  +  "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // Change the Cell color of the selected cell.(if record already found ind databae)
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
        SaveRecordtoDB();
    }
}
```

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.red;`

Comment: there is no 
    .defaulcellstyle.backcolor= color.red   
after the cells[0]

Comment: For [individual cells](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17728171/3773066).

Comment: Additionally, instances of classes which implement `IDisposable` such as `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataAdapter` should be wrapped in `using` statements as per [this example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection).

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer to my own question.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
```

it works perfectly fine!

Comment: That will change the `BackColor` of the entire `Row`.  If you just want to set the `BackColor` for an individual `Cell`, see my answer below.

Comment: Actually, I deleted my answer because you don't want to be accessing the database in `CellFormatting` event handler.  The answer linked by @OhBeWise above is exactly what you are looking for if you want to format an individual `Cell`.