# Set the Backcolor of DataGridview Column Based on Editable Property

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Im populating a Datagridview from Database by directly assigning the Data Table.There are some Columns in the Datagridview that are editable and some that are not.I want to set the color of the editable Columns to say 'Yellow'.

I know that i can set the color of a Column like

```
myGrid.Columns["myColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

But how to check the editable propety and set color based on that?

UPDATE:
This is what i'm looking for... the yellow cells should be editable ..Basically the cells under say WholeSaleRate,Retail Rate.. etc should be editable .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i could understand your question you want to changed the color of an editable `cells` of `datagridview`?

You can achieve this by using `DataGridViewCellFormattingEvent` event of the `datagridview` and check the column if it is `readonly` then change the background of a `datagridviewcell`.

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried it .. but the yellow is showing up for non editable cells and is random..

Comment: i added the `!` before `dgv` in the `if statement`

Comment: This is what im using 
        `private void dgvGetData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!dgvGetData.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            
        }`

Comment: use  this if statement `if(!dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)`

Comment: In the datagridview column settings did you set some of your non-editable column to `readonly`? it should work properly.

Comment: I think so.. this is the full code for binding the grid http://paste.ofcode.org/XmmGJHMi2AeS2zcx7S7zcF .. Could you please check..

Comment: if manually go to the designer and in the small arrow at the top right corner there is a menu that will appear and check the `enable editing` and go to `edit columns` and set all non-editable columns to `readonly ` property.

Comment: I have set `ReadOnly=false` for  3 columns .. Only 1 cell appears yellow.The other 2 appears yellow only after i click on it..

Comment: Did you left the `enable editing` checked? it should work fine by now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118503/discussion-between-shift-n-tab-and-techno).

Comment: Where should i set this property ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`RowPostPaint` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender,
    DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows )
    {
        if ( row.Cells["myColumn"].Value == "editable" )
            row.Cells["myColumn"].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        else
            row.Cells["myColumn"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

You can also override the paint method, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553181/4875631).

Comment: Thanks .. but keep getting this Error `object' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` for rows.Cells

Comment: One sec, looking into it.

Comment: Try now. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks ... but i cannot iterate by giving column names like this row.Cells["myColumn"].Value .. is there a way to iterate this is in a for each loop.

Comment: If you're just looking for one column, then access it directly with `row.Cells[1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118495/discussion-between-frankerz-and-techno).

Comment: This doesn't check if the columns are editable but rather check if the  cell **`value`** has the text 'editable'

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample code to make a column editable, dgvSample is the DataGridView that you added in form. Here i have made all odd columns editable. So, In same way you can have a  hidden column with a checkbox and check if its editable and achieve the same.

```
dgvSample.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dgvSample.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string[] values = new string[] { "1", "Name" };
    dgvSample.Rows.Add(values);
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow r = dgvSample.Rows[dgvSample.Rows.Count - 1];
        r.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    else
    {
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```