# Change color of datagridview row depending on value C#

Tags: c#

I have datagridview which is populated with 6 columns product id,product name,features,price,quantity and total price. All product with 0 quantity is automatically removed from the datagridview. My questions is how do I change color of the cell in "Quantity" if:

1. If quantity is less than 20 color orange
2. If quantity is less than 10 color red

Please bear with me as I am new to programming. I am required to do this for the inventory system we made for our capstone project.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it a web based or Winform application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing datagridview cell color dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728009/changing-datagridview-cell-color-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

you must first foreach on data grid view rows like following :

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
```

then foreach on cell

```
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in Myrow.Cells)
```

and then convert cells data to int32 and then use `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGridView1.Rows) 
        {       
     foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in Myrow.Cells)
    {       if (Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value)<10)
            Myrow .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.red;
             else if(Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value)<20) 
Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.orange;    
    }


        }
```

Comment: you're Welcome .please Mark answer if its working .To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.