# Setting datagridview cell background color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to check if condition of the active column is equals to false and it will set cell color row into red but it does not change the row color even the active column is false

This is the output shown:
[image: This is the output shown]

```
dgv_loadout.DataSource = ouput.ToList();

var activate = db.Users.ToList();
foreach (DataGridViewRow color in dgv_loadout.Rows)
{
    if (activate[color.Index].Active == false)
    {
        dgv_loadout.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to set the style of the `DataGridViewRow`, not the `DefaultCellStyle`. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728009/changing-datagridview-cell-color-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `BackColor` for specific cells.

```
for(int col = 0; col < dgv_loadout.Columns.Count; col++)
{
     [your_row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

If that doesn't work, check that your conditional is getting hit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dg = sender as DataGridView;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dg.Rows)
        {
            //your condition
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[0].Value);
            if (id == 1)
            {
                dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

I used RowsAdded event just for test.