# How to data grid view cell format based on SQL select query. (vb.net)

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm new to VB.NET I'm coming from a world of PHP. I am trying to take my web based program and turn it into a desktop application. I have done some searching around here but nothing is pointing me in the right direction.

This is a snip from my PHP

```
    $sql = "SELECT tblUnitMaster.UnitID, tblUnitMaster.JobCode, 
    tblUnitMaster.ReadyToShip, tblUnitMaster.TestComplete, 
    tblUnitMaster.APCD, tblUnitMaster.APHOD, tblUnitMaster.UnitLocation,  
    tblJobMaster.NatAccount, tblUnitMaster.JobNumber, 
    tblUnitMaster.ProductionReady, tblUnitMaster.EngineeringReady FROM 
    tblJobMaster\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN tblUnitMaster\n"
    . "ON tblJobMaster.JobNumber=tblUnitMaster.JobNumber\n"
    . "WHERE tblUnitMaster.UnitLocation = 'Bay_1' ";


   while ($row=$result->fetch_array())
  {

  echo "<tr>";

  if($row[2]> NULL)
  echo '<td bgcolor=#001EFF><font size=3><a 
  href="http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmUnitMaster2.php?JobNumber=' . $row[8] . 
  '&UnitID=' . $row[0] . '&Username=' . $Username . ' 
  ">',substr($row[0],0,4) , $row[1] , substr($row[0],4,3),'</a></font> 
  </td>'; // ReadyToShip

  else if($row[9]> NULL)
  echo '<td bgcolor=#820F0E><font size=3><a 
  href="http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmUnitMaster2.php?JobNumber=' . $row[8] . 
  '&UnitID=' . $row[0] . '&Username=' . $Username . ' 
  ">',substr($row[0],0,4) , $row[1] , substr($row[0],4,3),'</a></font> 
  </td>'; // ProductionReady

  else if($row[10]> NULL)
  echo '<td bgcolor=#646363><font size=3><a 
  href="http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmUnitMaster2.php?JobNumber=' . $row[8] . 
  '&UnitID=' . $row[0] . '&Username=' . $Username . ' 
  ">',substr($row[0],0,4) , $row[1] , substr($row[0],4,3),'</a></font> 
  </td>'; // EngineeringReady
```

All of that works as it should and is just a snip of what I'm trying to do in VB.NET

Now on to the issue at hand. I have a datagridview that I'm populating from a SQL query.

```vb
    'Data Grid OutSide

     Dim connecttion As New MySqlConnection("server=*********;" & 
     "user id=*******;" & "password=********;" & "database=*******;")

     Dim table0 As New DataTable()

     Dim adapter0 As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT UnitID, APHOD, 
         ReadyToShip, TestComplete, APCD FROM 
         forest.unit_master WHERE UnitLocation = 'Here'", connecttion)

     UnitLocationOutSide.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "UnitID"

     adapter0.Fill(table0)

     UnitLocationOutSide.DataSource = table0
```

This works in the sense of it populates the datagridview with all of the results form the query. My question is how do I go from having everything from the SQL query being displayed in the datagridview, to only having the "UnitID" being displayed? and the cell being a different color based on the results of the SQL query?

for example in PHP i would do the following

```
      if($row[2]> NULL)
       echo '<td bgcolor=#001EFF><font size=3><a 
       href="http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmUnitMaster2.php?JobNumber=' . 
       $row[8] . 
       '&UnitID=' . $row[0] . '&Username=' . $Username . ' 
       ">',substr($row[0],0,4) , $row[1] , substr($row[0],4,3),'</a> 
       </font> 
       </td>'; // ReadyToShip
```

so in that example I'm showing only the UnitID but that cell is blue because the ready to ship date is greater than NULL.

Sorry for being so long btw. back to the questions

How do I do a SQL query but only display the "UnitID" in the datagridview for VB.net?

How do I format that cell to a certain color based on the other criteria of the SQL query for VB.net?

Below is what i have working so far. Again for example what I'm looking to accomplish is lets say job 1113F-01 located outside has completed testing. all i want is for that cell background to be blue.

[image]

Below is what I have accomplished in PHP but am trying to convert it "so to say" to VB.NET

[image]

Comment: 1) Set the columns you want to hide to Visible = false ex: `YourDGV.Columns["YourColumnName"].Visible = false` and 2) Loop through the rows and set the cell background like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728009/changing-datagridview-cell-color-dynamically)

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors with your query.  That's really important.

Comment: @JacobH This does not work. 1) I'm not looking to hide columns. I'm trying to only display the 1 result.

Comment: If you don't want to hide columns, then change your query to only return the one column.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for your time. But this does not help

Comment: `But this does not help`  Blanket statements like this don't help us help you.  If you want help, you will have to explain this issue.  Why do these suggestions not work for you?

Comment: @LarsTech if you read the question's i have. I need to query all of those things but display only the "UnitID" but format that based off the other query results. So for example if the results for the query come back with "TestComplete" I want the DGV to show the "UnitID" but the cell to be the color blue.

Comment: @JacobH If you look at my PHP snip I think you will see I do indeed know how database and data structures work. What i don't know is how to manipulate that data in VB.NET. You are confusing your self. I do not want all of the columns to show up. I only want the "UnitID" column but i want the color to change based off other criteria.

Comment: Belittling your helpers is a really weird way to get help.

Comment: You have 11 columns in your grid and none are named UnitID.

Comment: @JacobH let me clarify. What you are seeing is 11 individual data grid view's. Each DGV is for a specific location. Where you see the "UnitID" column for each location.  I only included the VB.NET code for the 'Data Grid Outside or table0. Each DGV would be codded the same way. If you look at the picture I included you see on the outside DGV at the bottom there is the scroll bar because it is displaying all of the query output. I only want the "UnitID" to be displayed but I want that cell to be color coded.

Comment: @LarsTech I don't mean it for to come across as belittling, I'm only trying clarify my issue and what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Edited post to show PHP result. I'm looking to accomplish the same thing but in VB.NET

Comment: But why didn't the link provided by @JacobH in the first comment not work?  All you would need is to check the value then set the color.

Comment: @LarsTech The reason that doesn't work is because than I get the scroll bar on the bottom of the DGV with a bunch of black spaces. I'm looking to do all of the formatting in the background and displayed much like i have in my PHP code.

Comment: Well, your PHP isn't using a DataGridView, so you are going to have to adapt to how a DataGridView does things.  So the *real* problem here is the ScrollBar and whatever this black space thing is?  I don't see black spaces on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your data to populate list of your desired custom class.
then go through the datagridview after databind is complete to format the cells the way you want. I put this together rather quickly, so lots of improvements can be done but it gives you the general idea of what I think it is you are trying to achieve.

Here's a very minimal example...

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridviewCustomCellColor_58084907
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<dgvEntry> dgv1_Data = new BindingList<dgvEntry>();
        BindingList<dgvEntry> dgv2_Data = new BindingList<dgvEntry>();
        BindingList<dgvEntry> dgv3_Data = new BindingList<dgvEntry>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initializeDGV();
            makesomedata();
        }

        private void makesomedata()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                dgv1_Data.Add(new dgvEntry($"jobid{i}", i % 2 > 0 ? "complete" : "incomplete"));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                dgv2_Data.Add(new dgvEntry($"jobid{i} with longer title", i % 4 > 0 ? "complete" : "incomplete"));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgv3_Data.Add(new dgvEntry($"jobid{i}", i % 3 > 0 ? "complete" : "incomplete"));
            }
        }

        private void initializeDGV()
        {
            dgv_1.DataSource = dgv1_Data;
            dgv_2.DataSource = dgv2_Data;
            dgv_3.DataSource = dgv3_Data;
            dgv_1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            dgv_2.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            dgv_3.Columns[1].Visible = false;

            dgv_1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv_1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dgv_2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv_2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dgv_3.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv_3.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

            dgv_1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dgv_2.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dgv_3.RowHeadersVisible = false;

            dgv_1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            dgv_2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            dgv_3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

            dgv_1.BackgroundColor = BackColor;
            dgv_2.BackgroundColor = BackColor;
            dgv_3.BackgroundColor = BackColor;

            dgv_1.DataBindingComplete += dgvDoneBindingData;
            dgv_2.DataBindingComplete += dgvDoneBindingData;
            dgv_3.DataBindingComplete += dgvDoneBindingData;
        }

        private void dgvDoneBindingData(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            //color the cells accordingly
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in ((DataGridView)sender).Rows)
            {
                switch (((dgvEntry)item.DataBoundItem).jobstatus)
                {
                    case "complete":
                        item.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case "incomplete":
                        item.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            //the resizing shenanigans
            //autosize to get the width you need
            dgv_1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dgv_2.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dgv_3.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            int width1 = dgv_1.Columns[0].Width;
            int width2 = dgv_2.Columns[0].Width;
            int width3 = dgv_3.Columns[0].Width;

            //don't need autosize anymore
            dgv_1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgv_2.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dgv_3.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

            //set the column width
            dgv_1.Columns[0].Width = width1;
            dgv_2.Columns[0].Width = width2;
            dgv_3.Columns[0].Width = width3;

            //set the datagridview width
            dgv_1.Width = width1 + dgv_1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Right + dgv_1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Left + dgv_1.Columns[0].DividerWidth + 3;
            dgv_2.Width = width2 + dgv_2.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Right + dgv_2.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Left + dgv_2.Columns[0].DividerWidth + 3;
            dgv_3.Width = width3 + dgv_3.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Right + dgv_3.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Left + dgv_3.Columns[0].DividerWidth + 3;

            //set the datagridview height
            dgv_1.Height = dgv_1.ColumnHeadersHeight * (dgv_1.Rows.Count + 2);
            dgv_2.Height = dgv_2.ColumnHeadersHeight * (dgv_2.Rows.Count + 2);
            dgv_3.Height = dgv_3.ColumnHeadersHeight * (dgv_3.Rows.Count + 2);

        }
    }

    public class dgvEntry
    {
        public string jobid { get; set; }
        public string jobstatus { get; set; }

        public dgvEntry(string JobId, string JobStatus)
        {
            jobid = JobId;
            jobstatus = JobStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

In my example, the 3 datagridview `dgv_1 dgv_2 dgv_3` are in a FlowLayoutPanel

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is tagged vb.net.

Comment: I will defiantly give this a try and let you know how it works out.

Comment: @elliottdan, I refactored my code to get closer to your desired output, though it comes at the cost of not being able to scroll.