# change datagridview cellstyle border color

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to change the cell border colors based on the background color of the cell

this is what i have used

```
'Draw custom cell borders.
        Using Brush As New SolidBrush(grdList.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, e.CellBounds)
        End Using

        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground)
        Debug.Print(e.CellStyle.BackColor.ToString)
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds, e.CellStyle.BackColor, 1, _
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, e.CellStyle.BackColor, 1, _
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, e.CellStyle.BackColor, 1, _
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, Color.Black, 1, _
                                 ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
```

this is the result

[image]

i dont what the white lines currently seen

Comment: You dont want white, but what do you want? it looks like you are trying to draw black lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option you can set border styles yo none:

```
Me.DataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None
```

Then handle `CellPainting` event and paint borders:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, _
    e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting

    If (e.ColumnIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0) Then Return
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
    Dim r = e.CellBounds
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Top)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, r.Left, r.Bottom, r.Right, r.Bottom)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem applying the answer. Also you may want to take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154847/how-do-you-draw-a-border-around-a-datagridview-cell-while-its-being-edited) that describe about custom borders problem when editing.

Comment: Setting `e.Handled` to true is dangerous. Setting the value of a *DataGridViewTextBoxCell* will overlay it, resizing does not over-paint everything and leaves a big mess. Better solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553181/419581