# How to change width of cell border thickness in gridview windows forms?

Tags: vb.net, cell

I can easily change cellborderstyle in visual studio to none or fixed3d or single. But the single line is one pixel width. I want thicker, how do I change that.

Comment: I think there is no simple way to do it. You will have to do your own painting as explained in this SO post: [How do you draw a border around a DataGridView cell while it's being edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154847/how-do-you-draw-a-border-around-a-datagridview-cell-while-its-being-edited).

Comment: This looks usefull. Does it resize well? Well I will check it tomorow at work.

Comment: It should, as OnPaint will be called repeatedly during resizing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set gridview cell border thickness in vb.net windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704025/how-to-set-gridview-cell-border-thickness-in-vb-net-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could get without drawing your own would be to set the DividerWidth property to your desired thickness

```
    For Each DgvCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        DgvCol.DividerWidth = 10
    Next
```

Edit-
To set row divider height I might use the row prepaint event to spare resources on load:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DividerHeight = 5
End Sub
```

Comment: Well what about borders of datagrid?

Comment: Oops, I thought you were referring to the cells. Maybe what you could do is put the dgv into a panel which has padding set  to your desired thickness and change the background color to  color you want -I edited my answer

Comment: Since the panel becomes the border, you would want the grid to have no border then.

Comment: I was reffering to the cells, was thinking your solution only thickens lines between cells, Can you post your old answer pls, since I want to see the code.

Comment: Previously I suggested the DividerWidth on the DGV Columns

Comment: Well this doesnt work on the first line of cells, since it id just for between the cells as I fought. And since you cannot set datagrid border width it does not work.