# How to paint the border of the selected Row in a WinForms DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

[image]I have an custom control derived from the old [WinForms DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid).
I want to draw a border around the selected row when a User clicks it: the Row border, not a Cell's border, or change the Row's background color, etc.

[image]

Like the row in the graphics example (a red line on the 3rd row of the DataGrid).
I don't want it to be like the first row, with a blue background.

[image]

I saw this question:
[How do you draw a border around a DataGridView cell while it's being edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154847/how-do-you-draw-a-border-around-a-datagridview-cell-while-its-being-edited)
I cannot implement this because the DataGrid doesn't have a `CellPainting` event.
Trying something different, I have an error on `.Selected`:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && 
    e.RowIndex != -1 && dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected)
```

Comment: Anybody help..? Suggestion?

Comment: Well, it has been suggested to use the CellPainting event. Did you try? (To create an event you go to the properties window of the DGV and in the event pane doubleclick the event name)

Comment: Example : `private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    int yourcolumnindex = 2;  // use your own condition!
    if (e.RowIndex != yourcolumnindex) return;

    e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);
    Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
    r.Height--;      r.Width--;`

...

Comment: `if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, r.Left, r.Top, r.Left, r.Bottom);
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, r.Right, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Top);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, r.Left, r.Bottom, r.Right, r.Bottom);
    e.Handled = true;
}`

Comment: I dont have event  CellPainting,only similar like this what i see is Paint...

Comment: @TaW The OP is using the old WinForms' [Datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid)

Comment: Ah, not a good idea and obvisously even after 20+ hours a wrong Tag and Text.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -

Comment: I dont understand what you saying,what is element if not DataGridView,GridView or DataGrid.Data is on table what is it than?

Comment: __You need__ to tell __us__! Select it and look into the properties window!! I will be one of the 3..

Comment: I add screenshot of Properties in Question ask....How i can do this what i want if @Jimmi  is right for old datagrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Grid looks like a Custom Control derived from the old [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid) control.

Since, based on comments, this appears to be the case, there's not really much to work with.
Subscribe to the `Paint` and `Scroll` events using the event handlers shown here, this allows to draw a rectangle along the borders of the selected Row, considering the Scroll offset and the vertical ScrollBar width (the ScrollBars are child controls of the DataGrid, not necessarily of the default size, usually returned by `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`).

You may not be able to:

- cast `DotKasa.Kontrole.MyDataGrid` directly to `DataGrid`. If you cannot, add the DataGrid Control to your Project's ToolBox (open the ToolBox, right-click inside it, select `Choose Items...`, find the DataGrid and tick it).
- use some of the native methods/properties shown here: the Custom Control may have hidden or overriden some of these to change the behavior without calling `base`.

Add this code to your Form and see how it goes:

```
int dataGridPenSize = 3;

private void MyDataGrid_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = GetDataGridCurrentRowRect(sender as DataGrid);
    if (rect != Rectangle.Empty) {
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, dataGridPenSize)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}

private void MyDataGrid_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    => (sender as Control).Invalidate();

private Rectangle GetDataGridCurrentRowRect(DataGrid dg)
{
    int scrollbarWidth = GetVerticalScrollBarWidth(dg);
    var bounds = dg.GetCurrentCellBounds();
    int upperLimit = dg.PreferredRowHeight + (dg.CaptionVisible ? dg.CaptionFont.Height + 4 : 0);
    if (bounds.Y <= upperLimit) return Rectangle.Empty;
    var rect = new Rectangle (
        new Point(dg.RowHeaderWidth, bounds.Y), 
        new Size(dg.PreferredSize.Width - dg.RowHeaderWidth - dataGridPenSize - scrollbarWidth, bounds.Height));
    return rect;
}

private int GetVerticalScrollBarWidth(DataGrid dg) {
    var vScroll = dg.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault();
    return vScroll == null ? 0 : vScroll.Width; 
}
```

Comment: Its Works Brother,thank you :) : ) : ) ,one more question how to change width of rectangle border to be more massive?

Comment: See the edit. The Vertical ScrollBar is also calculated. You can use `int dataGridPenSize` as a public property, to change it at run-time, if needed. The Pen Color could also be a public property.

Comment: this dont go well,its bold rectangle but when change selected row,on last row before click is stay rectangle with 1 width border,and that is case for any else behind click next row...if i change 6 different rows click,on last row is bold ok rectangle,but on other 5 is rectangle with 1 width....

Comment: one more question Jimi...Do you know how to remove background selection color on row on this old DataGrid? On the beggining my ask i place screenshot where is blue colored selected row,and i want to dont be that blue color,i want to be transparent backgroud color, to be just rectangle on selected row?

Comment: Have you noticed that I changed the code before your last comments? If you have two different borders, then you didn't implement this code as it is. + This code does not repaint the colored selection, it's not shown in a standard DataGrid. Your custom control may repaint it, but I cannot test that, I don't have that control. Try this code with a standard DataGrid and see whether you have a different behavior.

Comment: Yes,i notice but i think you dont understand what i am trying to say you...check ask question i add new picture,with blue rectangle,Selected row is paint with width 4,and before selected row,and before before selected row is painted with width 2,3 i guess...And that dont is rule,sometimes does,but when i scroll down up then in moments works fine,and on moments then dont...

Comment: If you have residual drawings (lines that persist on that DataGrid), you probably have not subscribed to the `Scroll` event, using the `MyDataGrid_Scroll` event handler, which erases the previous line. This code: `private void MyDataGrid_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e) => (sender as Control).Invalidate();`. You have to use this handler, as shown in the answer. Subscribe to it once, of course. Check whether you have other handlers of the same event.

Comment: I am subscribe with this line code i propose:this.dgRacuni.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.dgRacuni_Scroll);  Its ok,i dont want to bother you,just say me your think how to set transparent selection background row color to be transparent in old datagrid? On Picture that is light blue color...I try on properties od dg SelectionBackColor set but that dont work,and trough code i dont success too.Do you have any suggestion maybe for this? And once more thank you a lot for rectangle.

Comment: You're not bothering me, I'm just trying to determine the problem so I can fix it. There's the chance that your control doesn't raise the Scroll event when you click/select Items. To verify it, subscribe to the MouseDown and add `(sender as Control).Invalidate();` to the handler.

Comment: Now for me is the biggest problem to set transparent color for selection backround row.

Comment: See [this animation](https://imgur.com/a/3A8eusb), that's how I see the DataGrid. The selection background is not painted. If you're referring to the `SelectionBackColor`, set it to the same Color as the `BackColor` property. The same with the `AlternatingBackColor` property. Try also to Invalidate() in the `CurrentCellChanged` event (instead of the `MouseDown`, which is useful to test the difference when a selection is made).

Comment: Yes,thats is need me from animation like that exactly.Thats i want to make.I try all you say me I set this.dgRacuni.SelectionBackColor = dgRacuni.BackColor;  this.dgRacuni.AlternatingBackColor = dgRacuni.BackColor; and i call dgRacuni.Invalidate() in CurrentCellChanged method but the result is the same,i dont know what to do,all when do ,i didnt see the change...

Comment: If you don't see changes, maybe those methods are not called. Put breakpoints in the handlers and see whether the code breaks there. Otherwise, try with a new Project, add just that DataGrid and test it. Maybe post the Project somewhere (including the Custom Control), so I can give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

To have full control on appearance of the rows and columns, you usually need to create custom column styles by driving from one of the existing built-in column styles like [DataGridTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or [DataGridBoolColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridboolcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or the base [DataGridColumnStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Then you can customize the behavior by overriding properties and methods of the class.

You will find this article very useful:

- [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996485(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

**Example - Draw Border for DataGrid Row**

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "A");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "B");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "C");

    var dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    var ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn()
    { MappingName = "Id", HeaderText = "Id" });
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn()
    { MappingName = "Name", HeaderText = "Name" });
    dg.TableStyles.Add(ts);

    this.Controls.Add(dg);
    dg.DataSource = dt;
}
public class MyDataGridTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextBoxColumn
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager 
        source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
    {
        base.Paint(g, bounds, source, rowNum, backBrush, foreBrush, alignToRight);
        if (this.DataGridTableStyle.DataGrid.CurrentRowIndex == rowNum)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, bounds.Left - 1, bounds.Top,
                bounds.Right + 1, bounds.Top);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, bounds.Left - 1, bounds.Bottom -1 , 
                bounds.Right + 1, bounds.Bottom - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer,i resolve error with @Jimi answer.

Comment: Good to hear that. If Jimi's answer has solved the issue, don't hesitate to mark it as accepted :) - I knew it's rather an old question, but I wanted to keep this option here for future reader as it's usually the way to go when it comes to customizing legacy DataGrid appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something out and it works nearly like you wanted.

You can get acces to the bounds rectangle for each cell where you want to paint the borders red with this function:

```
dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(ColumnIndex, RowIndex, true)
```

I created a public rectangle list where i put all cellborder-rectangles i want to draw red.

```
public List<Rectangle> rectlist = new List<Rectangle>();
```

Then i added the datagridview_cellclick event and the datagridview_paint event and put following code in there:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        rectlist.Clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            rectlist.Add(dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(i, e.RowIndex, true));
            
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Rectangle rect in rectlist)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);
        }
    }
```

Everytime you click on a cell, this code will put all cell-border-rectangles from cells off the same row in the list. The datagridview.refresh() function will then call the datagridview_paint function. There you can draw the rectangles on the datagridview with the painteventargs. The only negative thing about this solution is, that the whole border of each cell is painted red.

It looks like this:
[dgv with red borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43gxc.png)

Comment: The OP is using the old [Datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid)

Comment: Btw, in a **DataGridView**, to draw a Row border, you need to use the `RowPrePaint` or `RowPostPaint` events, don't try to paint the DGV control itself.