# Cell selection hides behind image DataGridViewImageCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I'm using Winform DataGridView to display images. But when image fills cell, I don't see blue selection or in very low quantity. Please see: [image: actual behaviour]

When an cell is selected, I **expect** make cell whole transparent blue, not just sides or sides which isn't occupied by image. like:

[image: expected behaviour]

Currently I tried coloring blue myself in paint event but it updates too frequently which hangs software.

I also modify image to look bluish in selection changed event, but again it slows down software.

Is there fix to this ? any workaround or something ? without compromising performance ?

**EDIT:** This is source code on how I display images on datagridview:

```cs
int colms = 4; // total no. of columns in our datagridview

//this create 4 image columns in datagridview
for (int c = 0; c < colms; c++)
{
    var imgColm = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    imgColm.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    imgColm.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
    grid.Columns.Add(imgColm);
}

int colm = 0;
int row = 0;

//this get all images and display on datagridview 
foreach (var img in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\images"))
{
    if (colm >= colms)
    {
        row++;
        colm = 0;
        grid.Rows.Add();
    }
    ((DataGridViewImageCell)grid.Rows[row].Cells[colm]).Value = Thumb.GetThumbnail(img, ThumbSize.LowRes);
    colm++;
}
```

Currently cell painting I use just a workaround, [that draws border on selected cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170212/14919621). But its slow when data is large and secondly draws on unselected cell as well.

[image]

Comment: The image is not part of the cell's background. But before that, how do you populate the grid? `.DataSource` ? `.Rows.Add`? How do handle the `CellPainting` event? You can handle the `RowPostPaint` event instead to fill the selected cell with a semi-transparent bluish color. Please edit to add the relevant details.

Comment: As for the slow performance part, probably it's due to loading a big number of images to display. Consider [Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: @dr.null Please see my edit. VirtualMode looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two examples to test yourself regarding the performance and the fill style of the selected cells. Since your code snippet does not show in what context the code is called, especially creating the image columns part, and to avoid repeating unnecessary routines, use the grid designer to add 4 columns of type `DataGridViewImageColumn` and set the auto size and layout properties from there.

**Normal Mode**
In the Form's ctor, use `Reflection` to enable the grid's `DoubleBuffered` property to reduce the flicker. The `emptyImage` bitmap is the null value of the empty cells.

```cs
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    private Bitmap emptyImage;

    public SomeForm()
    {
        dgv.GetType()
            .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(dgv, true);

        emptyImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        foreach (var col in dgv.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewImageColumn>())
            col.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = emptyImage;
    }
```

Override the `OnLoad` method to populate the grid or to call a method for that.

```cs
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var imgFolder = @"Your-Image-Folder-Path";
        LoadImages(imgFolder);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        emptyImage.Dispose();
    }

    private void LoadImages(string path)
    {            
        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.Length; i += 4)
        {
            var files = allFiles.Skip(i).Take(4);

            dgv.Rows.Add(
                files.Select(f =>
                {
                    using (var img = Image.FromFile(f, true))
                        return Thumb.GetThumbnail(img, ThumbSize.LowRes);
                }).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Note, your `Thumb.GetThumbnail` method returns a new image so you need to dispose of the original image.

Implement the `CellPainting` event to draw everything except the [`DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewpaintparts?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and fill the selected cells with a semi-transparent color.

```cs
    private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {    
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground);
    
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            e.Value != null && e.Value != emptyImage &&
            (e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
        {            
            using (var br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, SystemColors.Highlight)))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Virtual Mode**
You need here to have data store to cache only the images you need to display. The images of each cell of the visible rows. For that, The `Cache` class is
created to manage the relevant functionalities including:

- Calculating the total number of rows required to display 4 images per visible row. So the `SetMaxRows` method should be called when the grid is first created and resized to recalculate the visible rows.
- Loading, creating, and caching the current visible rows images in a `Dictionary<int, Image>` where the keys are the cell numbers.
- Passing the requested images when the [`CellValueNeeded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) event is raised.

```cs
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    private readonly Cache cache;

    public SomeForm()
    {
        dgv.GetType()
            .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(dgv, true);
        dgv.VirtualMode = true;

        var imgFolder = @"Your-Image-Folder-Path";
        cache = new Cache(imgFolder, dgv.ColumnCount);
        dgv.RowCount = cache.GetRowCount();
        SetMaxRows();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        cache.Dispose();
    }

    private void dgv_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e) =>
        e.Value = cache.GetImage(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);

    private void dgv_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) => SetMaxRows();

    // Change dgv.RowTemplate.Height as needed...
    private void SetMaxRows() =>
        cache.MaxRows = (int)Math
        .Ceiling((double)dgv.ClientRectangle.Height / dgv.RowTemplate.Height);

    private class Cache : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<int, Image> dict;
        private readonly Bitmap nullImage;
        private int currentRowIndex = -1;

        private Cache()
        {
            dict = new Dictionary<int, Image>();
            nullImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        }

        public Cache(string path, int columnCount) : this()
        {
            ImageFolder = path;                
            ColumnCount = columnCount;
        }

        public string ImageFolder { get; set; }
        public int ColumnCount { get; set; }
        public int MaxRows { get; set; }
        public Bitmap NullImage => nullImage;

        public Image GetImage(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            var ri = rowIndex - (rowIndex % MaxRows);

            if (ri != currentRowIndex)
            {
                foreach (var img in dict.Values) img?.Dispose();
                currentRowIndex = ri;
                dict.Clear();
            }

            var i = (rowIndex * ColumnCount) + columnIndex;
            Image res = nullImage;

            if (!dict.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(ImageFolder)
                    .Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();

                if (file != null)
                {
                    using (var img = Image.FromFile(file, true))
                        dict[i] = res = Thumb.GetThumbnail(img, ThumbSize.LowRes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                res = dict[i];
            }

            return res;
        }

        public int GetRowCount()
        {
            var count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(ImageFolder).Count();
            return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / ColumnCount);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var img in dict.Values) img?.Dispose();
            nullImage.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Finally, the `CellPainting` event remains almost the same except that you get the null image from the `cache` instance.

```cs
    private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground);

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            e.Value != null && e.Value != cache.NullImage &&
            (e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
        {                
            using (var br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, SystemColors.Highlight)))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved ! Really impressive the way you wrote answer in very concise and straight forward way. Thanks so much !

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz You are welcome. Appreciate your kind words.